# Get Currency Symbol based on Timezone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a solution in JavaScript to find the currency symbol based on the timezone.

eg: `America/Los_Angeles ==> should be $`

I know:

```
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
```

this would give the currency symbol, but it's in the country code format. Looking for a timezone based solution.

Comment: I would recommend against this as a solution for inferring currency. For example, large parts of Canada, the USA, and Mexico are in the same time zone. If you must do this, perhaps split out the country in the timezone and then reference a table of country codes / languages to feed into `toLocaleString`

Comment: Do you have the user's time zone id already (i.e., America/Los_Angeles)? Because there's no way to know what country their in from their time zone. You'll have to create a map between the time zone and the currency.

Comment: Yeah I've the user's timezone already in my table